# Find usages of SharedPreference in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to find my usages of certain shared preferences?
You can't 'Ctrl + Click' them since they aren't methodes or variables and can't select them or use the find usages function from androidstudio.
I can use the find usages on the getBoolean() method, however this gives me every single shared preference instead of just the one i am looking for.

Comment: A side note: I would recommend to start using constants for the key names of you preferences. This not only prevents bugs due to typos, but also makes it easy to search for usages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the key of `SharedPreference` by just `Ctrl+Shift+F` or click on Edit -> Find -> Find in path .

Select the desired module where you want to search and you are good to go .

Comment: I didn't know you could search through the entire project this way - helped me out allready, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no special support for this in Android Studio. You need to do a regular text search for `getBoolean("preferenceName"`.

Answer (score 0):

Search for

> getSharedPreferences("pref_name"

in Edit -> Find -> Find in Path...
This will display occurences where you used that specific SharedPreference.